# Apply "upgrade" certain packages with apt

Tags: apt

I need to update my version of OpenSSL and so I looked to implement an "upgrade", but I do not want my versions of php and apache is updated, that I can do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install <package>
```

From `man apt-get`:

```
--only-upgrade
           Do not install new packages; when used in conjunction with install,
           only-upgrade will install upgrades for already installed packages
           only and ignore requests to install new packages. Configuration
           Item: APT::Get::Only-Upgrade.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can download the packages but not install them. Try:

`sudo apt-get -d upgrade packageName`

Where `-d` or `--download` will download package files but does not install them.

Comment: Anytime. Enjoy!!

Comment: @user3680708: Also can you please upvote my answer? :)